# How to find number of empty lines in RichTextBox C#?

Tags: c#, count, richtextbox

I found the count of all lines with this code:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.Lines.Length.ToString());
    }
```

How can I find the number of empty lines only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-6.0)

> `.Count()` iterates over given sequence and increment the count if the predicate returns true.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     var emptyLineCount = richTextBox1.Lines.Count(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
     MessageBox.Show(emptyLineCount);
}
```

After applying `.Count()` with given condition, `emptyLineCount` variable will store integer value which denotes number of empty lines in give rich text box.

---

[`richTextBox1.Lines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) returns an array of string and you can use `.Count()` method from `System.Linq` to get the count of empty or null
lines from `string[]` i.e. Lines

To check given line is empty or not we used [`string.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0) function, which returns `true` if the string argument is empty otherwise return `false`